# quoteplus and quotestar not available in vim

Tags: vim

I am using vim version 8.0. I have compiled it locally and here is the output of features included displayed by `vim --version`:

```
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
+balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
+browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con_gui  -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xpm
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xterm_clipboard   <----
+ex_extra        -mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
```

As can be seen xterm_clipboard is enabled. I am trying to use copy from one instance of vim to another. In case it is relevant, I am using vim over SSH.

When I do `"+yy` and try to do `"+p` in another vim session, I don't get the desired line in the target session. Another peculiar thing: When I do `:reg` in my vim window, I don't see the `"+` and `"*` registers listed anywhere. Even `:reg +` doesn't give anything. What am I missing here?

Comment: When I do "+yy and try to do "+p **in another vim session**.. pls explain what do you mean by `in another vim session`? do you mean different vim processes?

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean

Comment: Weird. The issue resolved itself once I logged out and logged in to the machine. Only difference was that I had enabled ForwardX11 and ForwardX11Trusted in my .ssh/config

Comment: yes, read the `:h "=`,  they are required if you want to use `+` reg.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved itself once I logged out and logged in to the machine. Only difference was that I had enabled ForwardX11 and ForwardX11Trusted in my .ssh/config – cauthon14